# c++ linked list storing strings

Tags: c++, string, linked-list

I am creating a custom linked list class to store strings from a program I created for an assignment. We were given a linked list handout that works for ints and were told to retool it for string storage, however I am running into an error when trying to run it.

I'm getting the error ""terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
what(): basic_string::_S_construct null not valid"" (which I searched around and found it was because of a string being set to null, however I do not know how to fix the error, I'm guessing it is with line 8 but I've toyed around with it to no success.) I've searched around and looked through the similar questions but could not find anything that helped.

```
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <iomanip>
    using namespace std;

   struct node {
   node(string current) { data=current; next=NULL; }
   string data;
   node *next;
    };

    class list {
    public:
      list(int N=0, string current);
      ~list();
      bool empty() const { return N == 0; }
      void clear();

      void insert(int, const string &);

      void push_front(const string &current);

      friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, const list &current);

    private:
      int N;
      node *head;
      node *findnode(int);
      };

    list::list(int M, string current) {
      N = M;
     head = new node;
     for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
       insert(0, current);
    }

   list::~list() {
      clear();
     delete head;
    }


    void list::clear() {
      while (!empty()) remove(0);
    }

    void list::insert(int i, const string &din) {
      node *p = new node(din);
      node *pp = findnode(i-1);
      p->next = pp->next;
      pp->next = p;
      N++;
    }

    inline
    node *list::findnode(int i) {
      if (i == -1)
        return head;
      node *p = head->next; 
      while (i--)
        p = p->next;
      return p;
    }


    void list::push_front(const string &current) {
      head = new node;
      head->next;
    }

    ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const list& current)
    {
     out << current;
     return out;
   }


    const string rank[] = { "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
                            "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" }; 
    const string suit[] = { "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" };

    string random_card(bool verbose=false) {
        string card;

        card = rank[ rand()%13 ];
        card += " of ";
        card += suit[ rand()%4 ];

        if (verbose)
          cout << card << "\n";

        return card;
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        bool verbose = false;
        int seedvalue = 0;
        string stop_card = "Queen of Hearts";

        for (int i=1; i<argc; i++) {
          string option = argv[i];
          if (option.compare(0,6,"-seed=") == 0) {
            seedvalue = atoi(&argv[i][6]);
          } else if (option.compare(0,6,"-stop=") == 0) {
            stop_card = &argv[i][6];
          } else if (option.compare("-verbose") == 0) {
            verbose = true;
          } else 
            cout << "option " << argv[i] << " ignored\n";
        }

        srand(seedvalue);


        list deck[4];


        while (1) {
          string card = random_card(verbose);
          char first[10];
          char second[10];
          sscanf(card.c_str(), "%s of %s", first,second);

        // reverse engineer card suit and rank

          int index2;

          //suit index
          for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
            if(suit[i]==second){       
              index2=i;
            break;
          }
          }

          deck[index2].push_front(first);

        if (card.compare(stop_card)==0){
          break;
        }

        }


     // print formatted table contents to stdout 
    cout << "Clubs : "; 
       cout << setw(3) <<  deck[0];
     cout << endl;

     cout << "Diamonds : ";
       cout << setw(3) <<  deck[1];
     cout << endl;

     cout << "Hearts : ";
       cout << setw(3) << deck[2];
     cout << endl;

     cout << "Spades :  ";
     cout << setw(3) << deck[3];
     cout << endl;

    }
```

Comment: This isn't valid C++. The constructor for `list` has a default value for the first argument, and none for the second. Did we forget something? Likewise with `head = new node;` The `node` class doesn't have a default-constructor. *Please post valid code.*

Comment: @WhozCraig gee golly mister, thanks for all the help, man! both the constructor and the node class are verbatim from our handout, so that's what I have to use.

Comment: What compiler toolchian are you using that recognizes this: `list(int N=0, string current);` as *valid* C++? It isn't. Neither is `head = new node;` for a class `node` with no default-compliant-constructor. If this is *verbatim* what you're instructor handed you, you may want to ask whether you should fix *their* bugs while forming your assignment response, or just keep the code broken as-is. I'll look at the code, but things like "line 8" mean nothing without a comment marking the source where that is. (line:8 in this post is `struct node {`, for example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following are significant problems that will either hinder building (read: compile-time bugs) or actual runtime. This makes no claim these are *all* the bugs, but its certainly worth considering. I should note right off the top that the concept of a "sentinel" head-node allocation is almost- **never** needed in linked list management, and this code is not one of the exceptions. If the list is "empty" `head` should be null. If it isn't empty, `head` should *not* be null. Its just that simple, and this code would be leaps-and-bounds simpler if that were followed.

With that, read on.

---

**Invalid Code:**

```
list(int N=0, string current);
```

Reason: C++ requires all arguments **following** the first argument that is provided a default value to also have default values. This would be valid if N was the second parameter, or if `current` was also given a default value (or of course ,if *neither* had default values). All of the following are valid:

```
list(int N, string current);
list(int N, string current = "");
list(int N=0, string current = "");
```

As-written, it will fail to compile.

---

**Invalid code:** No matching constructor available

```
head = new node;
```

Reason: The structure `node` does not defined a default-compliant constructor (one that either has no parameters, or all parameters with default value provisions) but *does* specify a non-default constructor (one that requires at least one parameter). As a result, the language-supplied default constructor is *not* auto-generated and there is no `node::node()` constructor to be found.

---

**Incorrect Code:** Expression result is unused

```
void list::push_front(const string &current) {
    head = new node;
    head->next; // THIS LINE
}
```

Reason: This code blindly overwrites whatever is currently occupied in the `head` pointer with a new (invalid, see above for why) node allocation. Anything that was in `head` prior is leaked forever, and `current` is unused whatsoever. Fix this by allocating a new node with `current` as the value, settings its `next` pointer to `head` and `head` to the new node:

```
void list::push_front(const string &current) 
{
    node *p = new node(current);
    p->next = head;
    head = p;
}
```

---

**Infinite Recursion**

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const list& current)
{
    out << current;
    return out;
}
```

Reason: This code literally invokes itself. Recursively. Forever (well, until you run out of call-stack space).

---

**NULL Pointer Dereference**

```
inline node *list::findnode(int i) 
{
    if (i == -1)
        return head;
    node *p = head->next;
    while (i--)
        p = p->next;
    return p;
}
```

Reason: This will walk the list uninhibited by validity checking for  `i` iterations. Now imagine what this does on an empty list (in your case, that means `head` is non-null, but `head->next` *is* null) when passed anything *besides* `-1`: It will return NULL for `i=0` and is outright undefined behavior for everything else.

---

**NULL Pointer Dereference**

```
void list::insert(int i, const string &din) 
{
    node *p = new node(din);
    node *pp = findnode(i-1);
    p->next = pp->next;
    pp->next = p;
    N++;
}
```

This assumes `pp` will *never* be null on return, and as we already discussed with the prior item, it most certainly *can* be when `head` is the sole node in your list, and is therefore "empty". This makes no attempt at checking `pp` for NULL prior to using it for dereferencing. This kid-gloves handling and the exceptions that have to be accounted for are directly related to maintaining a "sentinel" head node. The simplest way to fix it is to (a) Don't use sentinel nodes; use the universal sentinel *value* `nullptr`, and (b) *check your return values before using them.*

---

**Ambiguous Reference: rank**

```
card = rank[ rand()%13 ];
```

Reason: The standard library defines a special struct called [`std::rank`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/rank) used for determining the number of dimensions in a multi-dimension array. With the `using namespace std;` at the top of your code, the compiler is now forced to choose which one (the one in namespace `std` or the array you've defined prior to this code), and it cannot do so unequivocally. Thus it will not compile. Note: this is brought in by implicitly including [`<type_traits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits), which is likely included by `<string>`, `<iostream>`, `<iomanip>` or any of a number of other nested includes. You can solve it a number of ways, including (but not limited to) a creative `using` clause, renaming the `rank` array to something that doesn't conflict, using a functional wrapper around a local static `rank` in the function etc.

---

**Implicit conversion from signed to unsigned type** (minor)

```
srand(seedvalue);
```

Reason: [`std::srand()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand) takes an `unsigned int` parameter; you're passing a signed integer. Either `static-cast` to `unsigned int` or change the type of `seedValue` to `unsigned int`.

---

**Invalid Code**

```
list deck[4];
```

Reason: Class `list` does not have a default constructor. Recall the first item in this response. If you fix that, you will fix this as well.

---

And I didn't even *run* the code yet. I would *strongly* advise working on these issues, and give serious consideration to *not* using a "sentinel" node for your list head. Linked list code practically writes itself once you "know" a null `head` means the list is empty, a non-null `head` means it isn't.

I make no claims this is *all* the bugs. These were just ones I saw while reviewing the code, and all but one of them is *significant*.

---

**EDIT** Sample operator overload

Note: If you fix your linked list to use null as a head value when the list is empty (advised) this will need to change to simply start at `head` rather than `head>next`.

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const list& lst)
{
    const node *p = lst.head ? lst.head->next : nullptr;
    while (p)
    {
        os << p->data;
        if ((p = p->next)) // note: assignment intentional
            os << ',';
    }
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the help. sorry for the rough start out in the comments lol. I fixed most of them, but the infinite recursion problem, and that's because I can't figure out how to overload the << operator to got through my list.  (and I actually can't changed the usage of "rank"  as it is a required part of the assignment.) I believe the only error keeping it from compiling is operator overloading. Oh, and to answer your earlier question, it's g++ that allows me to compile that code.

Comment: @user2809124 Remind me not to use that compiler. The operator overload is pretty simple. Just write an enumeration loop, and for each node you visit, send the node data to the output stream. its braindead, so if you want a sample I can post one in this answer.

Comment: that would be helpful, I think I know what I should do (using a while loop to break if the node is null), but I'm not entirely sure how to implement it using linked lists (this is our first time seeing them outside of a lecture last week). Thanks.

Comment: @user2809124 Posted as requested. Take heed to the note this needs to change if you do as-advised as simply use a null `head` to indicate an empty list. And I'm serious about that code. It *is* invalid C++. Ask your instructor about the points mentioned. I wish you the best of luck. For a starter-attempt this isn't too bad at all. Believe me, we've seen worse.